# Elvis where the alternative is a sequence of expressions?

Tags: kotlin

I need to check whether a value is present in a map, and if it's not, do something else and return.

For reasons outside the scope of this code fragment, I need to do this *without manifesting null as a variable value*, that is, without any of the variables having a nullable type.

This is what I have so far:

```
fun matchVariable(x: Variable, y: Term, m: MutableMap<Variable, Term>): Boolean {
    if (typeOf(x) != typeOf(y)) return false
    val x1 = m[x]?:{
        m[x] = y
        return true
    }
    return x1 == y
}
```

The 'return true' gets an error message that return is not allowed here, so it seems the default for the Elvis operator cannot be a block of multiple expressions.

I could factor out those two lines into a separate function; that's the fallback solution.

But it feels like there should be a concise way to do this in line (while meeting the above criterion of not manifesting null as a variable value). Is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin's mutable map has an in-built function `getOrPut` for this use-case.

```
fun matchVariable(x: Variable, y: Term, m: MutableMap<Variable, Term>): Boolean             
{
    if (typeOf(x) != typeOf(y)) return false
    return m.getOrPut(x) { y } == y
}
```

Same code with explanation/comments.

```
fun matchVariable(x: Variable, y: Term, m: MutableMap<Variable, Term>): Boolean {
    if (typeOf(x) != typeOf(y)) return false

    // if m[x] exists, it will be returned by `getOrPut`
    // else m[x] will be set to y and y will be returned by `getOrPut`
    return m.getOrPut(x) {
        // you can do some operations here.
        print("Updating m[$x] = $y")

        // last line will be value to be 'put' in map and same value will be returned.
        y
    } == y // value returned by `getOrPut` compared with `y`
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin (and unlike Java), a bare block `{ }` is a lambda, and you can't use a return statement in a lambda unless it's either the argument of an inline higher-order function.

In cases where you want to use organizational braces the way you might do in Java, you can use the unscoped `run` function. So it looks the same as you have, but with `run` in front of the braces. Since `run` is an inline higher-order function, you can use `return` in it.

```
fun matchVariable(x: Variable, y: Term, m: MutableMap<Variable, Term>): Boolean {
    if (typeOf(x) != typeOf(y)) return false
    val x1 = m[x]?: run {
        m[x] = y
        return true
    }
    return x1 == y
}
```

Alternatively, the `also` scope function can be used to concisely do some side effect before returning something:

```
fun matchVariable(x: Variable, y: Term, m: MutableMap<Variable, Term>): Boolean {
    if (typeOf(x) != typeOf(y)) return false
    val x1 = m[x] ?: return true.also { m[x] = y }
    return x1 == y
}
```